# Rails 4 + Cucumber: Can't find checkbox element on page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Code in `new` method in Controller:

```
...
@categories = Category.all
...
```

Code in `new.html.erb` view:

```
<% unless @categories.nil? %>
    <% @categories.each do |t| %>
        <%= t.name %>
        <%= check_box_tag "categories[#{t.id}]", t.name %>

        <br />
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The HTML that gets rendered is:

```
  Entertainment
  <input id="categories_6" name="categories[6]" type="checkbox" value="Entertainment" />

  <br />
  Health
  <input id="categories_5" name="categories[5]" type="checkbox" value="Health" />

  <br />
  Politics
  <input id="categories_3" name="categories[3]" type="checkbox" value="Politics" />

  <br />
  Sports
  <input id="categories_8" name="categories[8]" type="checkbox" value="Sports" />

  <br />
  Tech
  <input id="categories_4" name="categories[4]" type="checkbox" value="Tech" />

  <br />
  Travel
  <input id="categories_7" name="categories[7]" type="checkbox" value="Travel" />

  <br />
  United States
  <input id="categories_1" name="categories[1]" type="checkbox" value="United States" />

  <br />
  World
  <input id="categories_2" name="categories[2]" type="checkbox" value="World" />

  <br />
```

In my Cucumber test, I would like to be able check categories that I have listed, and as such I have the following as my scenario/steps:

Step:

```
When /^(?:|I )check "([^"]*)"$/ do |field|
  check(field)
end
```

Scenario:

```
@javascript 
Scenario: a signed in user can post an article with an associated category
  Then I should see "Sign out"
  Then I should see "New Article"
  Then I should see "Hello"
  When I follow "New Article"
  And I fill in "Url" with "Hello_World_Article_URL.com"
  And I fill in "Initial comment" with "My first comment"
  And I check "categories_6"
  And I press "Create Article"
  Then I should see "Article created!"
  Then article url "Hello_World_Article_URL.com" should exist
```

However, this fails at the `And I check "categories_6"` step, reporting a Capybara ElementNotFound Error. I am unclear as to why referencing the checkbox by "id" did not work correctly. Does anyone have insight into what I may have done incorrectly or how I could go about fixing this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you use the checkbox name or label text instead of the id?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error with all of these.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
When (/^(?:|I )check "([^"]*)"$/) do |field|
  check(field)
end
```